# xgettext does not recognize strings defined as macroses

Tags: c, localization, gettext

I have some misunderstanding of how xgettext tool parses C source files
and gathers strings for further translation.

I use xgettext tool version 0.10.35 and
it turned out that it does not recognize strings defined like macroses during parsing.

For example we have test_xgettext.c file with next content:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define    _(str)         str

#define    STRING_1       _("string 1")

int main(void)
{
    printf(STRING_1);
    printf(_("string 2"));
    return 0;
}
```

If we run

> xgettext.exe test_xgettext.c -o test_xgettext.pot -k_

we will have test_xgettext.pot file with next content:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2016-09-01 12:39+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: ENCODING\n"

#: test_xgettext.c:10
msgid "string 2"
msgstr ""
```

Here we only have "string 2" in POT file, and my goal is
to gather both "string 1" and "string 2".

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Works for me. (xgettext 0.19.2 on linux)

Comment: @michalsrb I use my version on Windows 7 Professional. Not sure if I can change currently used version of xgettext.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't correctly recognize the language. Try adding "-L C" parameter. (E.g. in python mode the "string 1" gets skipped.)

Comment: @michalsrb "-LC" does not help, seems that there is a bug in my version of xgettext, or I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it works for *xgettext 0.10.35* if we use array instead of macro.

Modified source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define    _(str)         str

char    STRING_1[]  =       _("string 1");

int main(void)
{
    printf(STRING_1);
    printf(_("string 2"));
    return 0;
}
```

In this case we have next output in POT file (I left out not important lines):

```
#: test_xgettext.c:5
msgid "string 1"
msgstr ""

#: test_xgettext.c:10
msgid "string 2"
msgstr ""
```

It also turned out that it works as it was initially expected with xgettext version 0.19.8.1 (Windows 7 Professional). Source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define    _(str)         str

#define    STRING_1       _("string 1")

int main(void)
{
    printf(STRING_1);
    printf(_("string 2"));
    return 0;
}
```

Generated POT file:

```
#: test_xgettext.c:5
msgid "string 1"
msgstr ""

#: test_xgettext.c:10
#, c-format
msgid "string 2"
msgstr ""
```